# Is the function sum and the product, over the reals, unique?

Tags: real-analysis

If we define the set of the reals with its field properties,  order properties and the supremum  property, is it possible to find two different functions with the same properties as the sum and two different functions with the same properties as the product?

Comment: This is probably excluded by the fact that the only automorphism on the reals is the trivial one, though it might depend on which properties of the sum/product you're trying to preserve.

Comment: The product and the sum of two even functions are even.